# Get response from windows azure in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, azure-mobile-services

![I want to get the 'Custom message' from the Windows Azure were i written my server script to My windows 8 App.][1]

i have a scenario that i want to get return request from Windows Azure in Windows 8 .

My Azure Script `Request.Respond(Status.Codes.'OK')`

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need more information to be able to answer your question. Please be more specific. What have you done, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have an app that will insert data in to cloud database , i had written request.respond(status code,'My Message') in the azure server script , how do i return this response to my App

Comment: Please add to your post the following information, which will make it easier for other people to help you: the full server-side script; the client-side (Windows 8) code which is calling the service; any other information which will help the community understand your problem.

Comment: i tried with 'iservicefilter' to get response but i couldn't successfully implement it

Comment: guyz i have getting response in Mobileinvalidserviceexpection as my custome message in my programm , but it only catch if its invalidexpection error. pls help me

Comment: You should have request.respond(StatusCodes.OK, {message: "success"}); and from here we are looking for the same answer:)